# Debugging TestNG configuration failures

Tags: ant, testng

I'm running TestNG from Ant. I'm using my own test listeners. I'm refactoring the code and once a while I got

```
[testng] Total tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Skips: 7
[testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2
```

What will be the best approach to fix configuration failures ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HTML reports will tell you which configuration methods failed.