# TestNG Report details query

Tags: annotations, testng

I have a TestNG suite with `@Test : Total 14`

The TestNG Report for one of the execution which failed to even setup looks like this :

```
Total tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Skips: 14
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 17
```

What are these configurational failures count about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer HTML Reports for Configuration failures, mostly causing by Before and After variants of methods

Refer this SO post answered by Cedric Beust: [Debugging TestNG configuration failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881591/debugging-testng-configuration-failures)

And this Allure error reporting fix: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/569

Also setting TestNG verbose level to 10 may give more info:

```
<suite name="Suite" verbose="10">
```

Comment: @nullpointer, have you figured the error reasons? if so, post them, may be helpful to community